# Wrap text in ListView item in Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I wrap text in a Grid?

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="Users" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<User> items = new ObservableCollection<User>();
items.Add(new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42 });
Users.ItemsSource = items;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `DataTemplate` for the `GridViewColumn` and place `TextBlock`. Then it is possible to use `TextWrapping` property. Work example:

```
<ListView Name="Users">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>            
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="385">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="385">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```